# Using the geometry shader for instancing

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx, shader, geometry-shader

So I want to draw lots of quads (or even cubes), and stumbled across this lovely thing called the geometry shader.

I kinda get how it works now, and I could probably manipulte it into drawing a cube for every vertex in the vertex buffer, but I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it. The geometry shader happens between the vertex shader and the fragment shader, so it works on the vertices in **screen space**. But I need them in world space to do transformations.

So, is it OK to have my vertex shader simply pipe the inputs to the geometry shader, and have the geometry shader multiply by the modelviewproj matrix after creating the primitives? It should be no problem with the unified shader architecture, but I still feel queasy when making the vertex shader redundant.

Are there alternatives? Or is this really the 'right' way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly OK.

Aside from that, consider using instanced rendering (`glDrawArraysInstanced`,`glDrawElementsInstanced`) with vertex attribute divisor (`glVertexAttribDivisor`). This way you can accomplish the same task without geometry shader at all.

For example, you can have a regular cube geometry bound. Then you have a special vertex attribute carrying cube positions you want for each instance. You should bind it with a divisor=1, what will make it advance for each instance drawn. Then draw the cube using `glDraw*Instanced`, specifying the number of instances.

You can also sample input data from textures, using `gl_VertexID` or `gl_InstanceID` for coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on instancing, but it was slow. It limited me to entire cubes, so I couldn't cull any hidden faces, and instancing per quad is pointless because a 4x4 matrix that describes the transformation per quad is almost larger than just using 4 verts straight up.

Comment: Wich approach would be faster, performance wise? Geometry shader or instancing? Also approximately by how much?